# Regex: Capture from and to a specific point if it contains a specific word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the words in a link if they contain a specific word, in the case "policy".

For example:

`<a href="https://website/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Policy-October-2018.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Nature Policy (pdf, 1.9MB)</a></p><p>`

I want to capture: **Nature Policy (pdf, 1.9MB)**

I have managed to capture the end bit perfectly using the below regex but I can't get it to start from the first **>** symbol.

My Regex:

`(?i)[^">]*\bPolicy\b.+?(?=<)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ideally should not ever use regex to parse nested content like HTML.  That being said, if your input text would always only have a single non-nested anchor `<a>` tag, then the following regex pattern should work:

```
<a[^>]+>([^<]*\bPolicy\b[^<]*)<\/a>
```

### Demo

This pattern works by capturing, in the first capture group, the text content inside the anchor tag, provided that this text content contains the word `Policy`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

```
(?<=>).+?\bPolicy\b.+?(?=<)
```

I modified the beginning to use a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?<=>)`) that matches a `>` and then `.+?` which you already are using after the word `Policy`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sWNphQ/2